# An EDM downtempo prog-house song called *The Spectre* and the DC character called Spectre

Tags: history, electronic-music

Does Alan Walker's song [*The Spectre*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJnBTPUQS5A) have anything at all to do with the DC Comics character called [Spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(DC_Comics_character))?

Did he base his song off of the DC Character or not?

---

The comic character Spectre is a ghost-like character with the powers of DC's gods. He has no discernible weakness other than needing a human host<sup>[[Source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spectre_(DC_Comics_character)&oldid=958296769#Powers_and_abilities)</sup>.

[He kind of looks like Alan Walker.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/42/Spectre01.jpg/220px-Spectre01.jpg)

---

"The Spectre" - lyrics:

> Deep in the dark I don't need the light
>   There's a ghost inside me
>   It all belongs to the other side

---

Did the famous DJ base his song off of the DC Comics character?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the song, nor have I heard of Alan Walker, but I'm answering on the chance that you may not be a native English speaker.

In English, the word "Spectre" simply means, ghost, spirit or phantom, so my guess is that both the DC character and the song are derived from the normal meaning of the word rather than one copying from the other. There is nothing about the lyric that suggests anything more than the normal things associated with spectres; darkness, "the other side" etc.